# Execute code upon app termination in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm new to swift and programming so I'm not sure if or how this is possible, but could anyone tell me if I can designate code to be executed when the user terminates the app from the multitasking menu? I just have a line of code that I would like to execute at that time, but I'm not sure where to put it in my project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user terminates the app from the multitasking menu, your app is killed dead. It is not terminated "in good order". You do not get an event at that time. It's just like the scene in *2001: A Space Odyssey* where the scientists are already in suspended animation and HAL pulls the plug on them.

The art of Cocoa / iOS 8 programming is the art of the possible. Adjust your desires to fit the reality of the events you *do* get. You get an event when the user leaves your app, so if there is something you need to be sure to do, do it then, as you may never get another chance.

Answer (score 1):

As matt said, when the app is terminated from the multitasking menu, none of your code is run, it's just killed.

Try putting your code into the application delegate's [`applicationWillResignActive(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive:) method. This will run any time your app becomes inactive, though. In other words, more often (all the time) than being terminated in the multitasking menu. It'll run when there's an incoming phone call or text, I believe it will run if there is a notification with an alert, it will run when the user presses the home button.